# nodeJS multi node Web server

Tags: multithreading, node.js, webserver

I need to create multi node web server that will be allow to control number of nodes in real time and change process UID and GUID.

For example at start server starts 5 workers and pushes them into workers pool.
When the server gets the new request it searches for free workers, sets UID or GUID if needed, and gives it the request to proces. In case if there is no free workers, server will create new one, set GUID or UID, also pushes it into pool and so on.

Can you suggest me how it can be implemented?
I've tried this example http://nodejs.ru/385 but it doesn't allow to control the number of workers, so I decided that there must be other solution but I can't find it.

If you have some examples or links that will help me to resolve this issue write me please.

Comment: You realise nodejs has asynchronous evented IO right? It's specifically build so you _do not_ need a process per request. Using a process per request is both inefficient and will slow your server down to a crawl. If you want that then don't use nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this: http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think cluster will do it for you.
What you want is to use one process per request.
Have in mind that this can be very innefficient, and node is designed to work around those types of worker processing, but if you really must do it, then you must do it.

On the other hand, node is very good at handling processes, so you need to keep a process pool, which is easily accomplished by using node internal child_process.spawn API.

Also, you will need a way for you to communicate to the worker process.
I suggest opening a unix-domain socket and sending the client connection file descriptor, so you can delegate that connection into the new worker.

Also, you will need to handle edge-cases for timeouts, etc.

Comment: One process per request model with node is just plain stupid. Don't do it.

Comment: I have done a lot of load testing recently. I can say that Node.js is very efficient to handle hundreds or thousands of requests.  However, not suggest to use socket as it demonstrated some performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pgte/fugue   I use this.